# Регулярные выражения в findstr

Tags: windows, cmd

Хочу найти строки с помощью findstr, в которых только определенные простые числа:

`findstr /R "^[357]*" file.log`

Выдает много результатов, но не то что ожидается.

Comment: ниче про винды не знаю, но если выдаются все строчки, начинающиеся с этих цифр, попробуйте  `^[357]+$`

Comment: ^[357]*$ вот так сработало, спасибо за наводку